# Strange behaviour of Convert.FromBase64String

Tags: c#, base64

Why does the following code

```
var s =  "2I==";
var b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
var new_s = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```

end up with new_s being `2A==`?

`s` was originally a longer string (96 chars) but I couldn't include it because it is a secret key.

Comment: I suspect it's because `2I==` is effectively providing some bits for the padding value. Will analyze...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"2I==" represents the numbers 54, 8, (padding x2), as per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

In other words, the bits represented are:

```
110110 000100 XXXXXX XXXXXX
```

(Where X represents an "I don't care, it's from padding")

However, because the padding indicates that there's only one byte of information here, the last 4 bits from the second character are irrelevant. As ever, we can reformat the 4 pieces of 6-bit information into 3 pieces of 8-bit information, at which point it becomes clearer:

```
11011000 0100XXXX XXXXXXXX
```

You can see that the second byte must be padding, as some of its bits come from a padding character. So only the first character and the top two bits of the second character are relevant - it decodes to just the single byte 0b11011000.

Now when you *encode* 0b11011000, you know that you'll have two padding characters, and the first character *must* be '2' (to represent bits '110110') but the second character can be *any* character whose first two bits represent '00'. It just happens that `Convert.ToBase64String` uses 'A', which has 0 bits for the irrelevant parts.

The question in my mind is why an encoder would choose to use 'I' instead of 'A'. I don't *think* it's invalid to do this in Base64, but it's an odd choice.

Comment: Man you can reply fast.

Answer (score 4):

Jon Skeet has provided a good explanation for the observed behaviour. However, under most definitions of Base64, your input string would be considered invalid. The standards contain the following text:

> When fewer than 24 input bits are available in an input group, bits with value zero are added (on the right) to form an integral number of 6-bit groups.

- [RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421#section-4.3.2.4): Privacy Enhancement for Internet Electronic Mail
- [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.8): Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME)
- [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4): The Base16, Base32, and Base64 Data Encodings

[RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.5) puts further emphasis on this:

> The padding step in base 64 and base 32 encoding can, if improperly
> implemented, lead to non-significant alterations of the encoded data.
> For example, if the input is only one octet for a base 64 encoding,
> then all six bits of the first symbol are used, but only the first
> two bits of the next symbol are used.  These pad bits MUST be set to
> zero by conforming encoders [...]
> Decoders MAY chose to reject an encoding if the pad bits have not
> been set to zero.

We can assume that your original input consisted of a single byte having value `216` (`0xD8`). In binary:

```
11011000
```

This needed to be split up into 6-bit groups:

```
110110 00
```

And, per the quoted definition above, the last group needed to be padded with zeros:

```
110110 000000
```

Per the Base64 alphabet, `110110` (decimal: `54`) maps to the character `2`, whilst `000000` (decimal: `0`) maps to the character `A`. Adding the `=` padding to get a 24-bit group, the final result will be `2A==`. This is the only valid encoding for your original input.

Comment: +1 - This shows why the range from `2A==` to `2P==` will generate the same value `2A==`.  Then once `Q` is reached, the least significate bit of the two bit value will increment and you would get `2Q==`